# Icefaces InputFile component

Tags: jsf, icefaces, file-io

I've downloaded the ICEFaces 2.0.2 bin-files, but I cannot find the tag "inputFile"; I can only find a tag called "fileEntry"

What am I missing? I want to implement something like:

http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface

I've also added to my xhtml page the namespace:

```
xmlns:ice=http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component
```

But, netbeans tells that there's no library with that namespace.

Comment: The only component I found is **fileEntry** and it is in Advance Components... I think there's no **inputFile** anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, looking at the component-showcase in sample folder it says the following

> Deprecation Notice:
>
> The ice:inputFile component is deprecated in ICEfaces 2.
>
> A next generation file upload component ('fileEntry') is available as
>   part of the ICEfaces Advanced Components.
>
> For more information on the fileEntry component see the online
>   documentation.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: :Are you able to get `ace:FileEntry` component working, am able to get file system navigation popup open but the thing is `fileEntryListener` is not getting called on the server, i tried to put `actionListener` on `submit` button but still am not able to get that data out, have you ever been successful with getting `ace:FileEntry` component running?

Comment: Sorry, I never made it work so I gave up and moved to RichFaces (great UI library by the way)

Comment: ok, no problem, am kind of stuck on this one, anyways dump question, can we use two `UI` frameworks together on one page?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this webApp stuff, but for what I've read sure you can. There will be some conflicts between dependencies you will have to solve though. There's plenty of information about using, for example, IceFaces + PrimeFaces. Good luck !